# How do I append db field into a url string?

Tags: vb.net

I am not sure how difficult this is but I have checkboxList with value that is being populated from the database.

This is the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="sects">
```

The fieldname is doclist and I read the values into this:

```
While objReader.Read()
  With objReader
    Dim li As New ListItem(objReader(0).ToString())
    sects.Items.Add(li)
  End With
End While
```

It works great so far. Thanks in large part to the great help I get here.

However, we would like to have values associated with the sects.Items.Add(li) concatenated into a url.

The following is the url:

http://default.html and we would like to concatenate it so it looks something like this:

```
http://default.html?parts="+sects.Items.Add(li)+"&docs=answers&name=meter.zip"
```

This doesn't work. I get an error, "this does not produce a value

What we are trying to accomplish is to populate the checkboxList with url string containing the sects values within that url.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Sorry guys I just keep coming back for more. I do try to fix first though before coming here.

Comment: You want to select a single value?  Or if they select multiple items, do you want to capture them all?  Why put it it the URL?  For multiple values, consider a Session object.

Comment: Yes, @GrayFox374; great to hear from you again.

The users can select one or more urls. The idea is that if they click any of the urls, it displays the sections in a pre formatted layout.

According those 2 superb solutions you provided, they would depend in part on clicking a button, no?

Just like the previous assistance you provided (thaks again), rather than displaying the text, we would want them to now be displayed as links.

Comment: Yes, that code should be placed inside the button or link event that you wish to use to move to the default.html, which should properly be default.aspx.  I don't understand what you mean by "we would want them now to be displayed as links.  Please clarify.

Comment: Let's say for instance this solution you helped me a little earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617181/how-do-i-append-db-field-into-a-url-string

It displays a list of checkboxes based on how many records are on the db of course. Each checkbox has the values both populated inside the value="" property as well as display as text. For instance, you will see value="Miracle Alley" as well as the text Miracle Alley. We now want the values to be a link like your example below:
http://yoururl.com:31206/Page2.aspx?parts=1-000000001|1-000000002|1-000000003

Comment: Okay, so You want to display a link, but not necessarily move them there? As they are checking and unchecking you want to link to reflect the changes?

Comment: I feel so horrible that I am making you do this. It is possible that this is not possible or I am not explaining it well.

Right now, it creates a link below the checkboxes and that's not what I am asking for; I am truly sorry.

What we wanted is that instead of having Miracle Alley as value for a checkbox or text, we want < href="default.aspx?someval=somevalue&sects=miracle Alley"

This comes a link. Similary, instead of having Miracle Alley display as text, again it will display as a link.

Again, thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @GrayFox374, the solution would be something this:

            While objReader.Read()
                With objReader
                    Dim li As New ListItem(objReader(0).ToString())
                    sects.Items.Add("<a href='http://default.aspx'>" + sects.SelectedValue.ToString() + " &docs=answers&name=meter.zip</a>")

instead of this: sects.Items.Add(li) 

Problem I can't figure out how make it all work. Right now, the link is there but the values are not.

                End With
            End While

Comment: I just updated my solution (again).  Try it out.

Comment: EXACTLY what we are after!!!

Thank you for your expertise and incredible patience, @GrayFox374.

I will keep this name in mind and hope to repay you one day.

THANK YOU very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand better.  I have removed the link button and I have altered the list items so the the text shown is a URL that contains the database field in it, as a URL parameter.  The value remains the database field by itself.  But if I may ask, what kind of design is this? It looks very shaky.  Can you navigate to these pages with distinct data rendered? You want to allow multiple selections, but how can you take that into account by going this route.  And if you don't want the user to be able to have multiple selections, you should use a drop drown list instead.  I hope this works for you, but I am looking skeptically at the logic behind this requirement and its implementation.

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="sect" CssClass="checkAll" AutoPostBack="true" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT AppealNumber FROM Appeals"
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
        Dim objReader As SqlDataReader
        conn.Open()
        objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        '   |||||   Loop through the Reader to retrieve data    
        '   |||||   and set each checkbox to appropriate data from datasource
        While objReader.Read()
            With objReader
                Dim li As New ListItem("Default.aspx?parts=" + objReader(0).ToString(), objReader(0).ToString())
                sect.Items.Add(li)
            End With
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I missed the point you made here. I was so excited I forgot to read through. What they said they wanted was to add the db value into the checkbox value.

Then a user would select one or more checkboxes and the click something like "Get Checked items" and the values will be appended to the url to form complete url with parameters which will then redirected to another page for printing all the selected documents.

I felt it would be easier to add the url in the checkbox. I will find out if I screwed up.

Comment: Yeah, I think you wanted my first solution.  This doesn't append, but that one did.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sects.Items(//Index of Item).ToString()

http://default.html?parts="+sects.Items(//Index of Item).ToString()+"&docs=answers&name=meter.zip"
```

Or: (Its been awhile for asp but I think something like this is availible)

```
sects.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

The part `sects.Items.Add(li)` Is to add the object to the CheckBoxList

Comment: hi @Jmyster,

You are correct sects.Items.Add(li) adds objects to the CheckBoxList.

How do I replace this sects.Items.Add(li) with the url so that now the url shows up in checkboxlist control?

Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string urlappend = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        urlappend += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value + "_";
    }
```

you need to loop through the items in checkbox list and get their value appended as a string and then add that string to the URL, that way will get all values. Also in the above code I used "_" as separator to identify each item value.

In case if you want only selected items then you can add the following condition

```
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
        urlappend += CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value + "_";

    }
```